# Updating multiple nodes in Firebase but only to inform listener once

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure ( a bit more complicated than that, with multiple levels and branches)
I have a listener at the ZMainBranch, waiting for updates on different levels underneath.

I have a function that is based on a data changed on a different branch it updates this properties under the ZMainBranch.

The issue is updates on the ZMainBranch are done on a multi steps, which invokes the listener on the ZMainBranch multiple times.

[image]

What I would like to have is to do all my updates on one go so the listener would only be invoked once.

One solution is to update at the ZMainBranch level, but that requires reading the hole data, mapping it, changing what needs changing then writing, that is a lot to do for small changes here and there under the branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you perform multiple writes under a location, you can expect that an active listener at the location could get invoked multiple times.  There's not much you can do to avoid that.

Your alternative is to collapse all of your writes to different children into a single multi-location update.  It might also be possible to use a transaction, as long as all your clients are coordinated on writes at that location.

Read about multi location updates:

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for the reply and the Link, I will look into these options. I actually started building my new app after I watched all of your videos on firebase functions and async/await, thanks for these too :)